# Slow Boot Up on Display Port Compared to HDMI

Tags: linux, fedora, nvidia, hdmi, displayport

I installed my Nvidia GeForce GTX 1060 driver on my Fedora 37 following this [guide](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2015/fedora-nvidia-guide/) and everything seems to be working.  The problem I have is when I plug in my Display Port.  My screen would become black and it takes roughly 10 minutes or more for the system to fully boot into the desktop environment.  The weird thing is this issue doesn't happen when using the HDMI connection.  It takes about 1-2 minutes for the system to boot up.  I've searched everywhere for this symptom and people tend to point to the faulty cable.  I purchased a new cable from a reputable company and it didn't make any difference. I also looked at the thread posted in https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/black-screen-after-updating-to-6-1-5-200-fc37-w-nvidia-drivers/30759 and https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/multiple-displayport-displays-slow-boot-flickering/10132. My problem seems to be the same if I use the DP cable; otherwise, it doesn't apply.

In addition, I cannot see or get into the BIOS Screen with the DP cable attached but I can access the BIOS with the HDMI cable.  There was a fix from Nvidia, https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/nv-uefi-update-x64/, and luckily I had an old Windows drive that I installed on my system.  I was able to boot it up to do the update.  After that, I disconnected my Windows drive and boot off my M2 NVME Sata Drive with Fedora 37.

My current connection is one DP cable going from the graphic card to my monitor and daisy chained from one monitor to another terminated at the 3rd monitor.

Here's the result from the HDMI boot process:

```
systemd-analyze                                                                           
Startup finished in 13.680s (firmware) + 7.079s (loader) + 1.798s (kernel) + 12.596s (initrd) + 9.190s (userspace) = 44.346s 
graphical.target reached after 9.162s in userspace.

systemd-analyze blame | head -n 20                                                
1min 58.150s fstrim.service
     18.898s dnf-makecache.service
     13.071s sys-module-fuse.device
     13.036s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS1.device
     13.036s dev-ttyS1.device
     13.035s dev-ttyS18.device
     13.035s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS18.device
     13.034s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS12.device
     13.034s dev-ttyS12.device
     13.033s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS13.device
     13.033s dev-ttyS13.device
     13.033s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS11.device
     13.033s dev-ttyS11.device
     13.033s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS10.device
     13.033s dev-ttyS10.device
     13.033s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS14.device
     13.033s dev-ttyS14.device
     13.032s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS0.device
     13.032s dev-ttyS0.device
     13.031s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS15.device

systemd-analyze critical-chain                                                    
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @9.162s
└─multi-user.target @9.162s
  └─plymouth-quit-wait.service @6.550s +2.602s
    └─systemd-user-sessions.service @6.514s +23ms
      └─remote-fs.target @6.501s
        └─remote-fs-pre.target @6.501s
          └─nfs-client.target @2.964s
            └─gssproxy.service @2.945s +18ms
              └─network.target @2.941s
                └─wpa_supplicant.service @8.286s +10ms
                  └─dbus-broker.service @2.248s +19ms
                    └─dbus.socket @2.150s
                      └─sysinit.target @2.147s
                        └─systemd-resolved.service @2.045s +101ms
                          └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @1.973s +54ms
                            └─import-state.service @1.915s +30ms
                              └─local-fs.target @1.914s
                                └─boot-efi.mount @1.902s +11ms
                                  └─boot.mount @1.569s +11ms
                                    └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49e7acd7\x2d0f9e\x2d4eea\x2d905a\x>
                                      └─local-fs-pre.target @1.497s
                                        └─lvm2-monitor.service @839ms +655ms
                                          └─dm-event.socket @820ms
                                            └─system.slice
                                              └─-.slice
```

Here's the result from DP connection.  The difference is 7 minutes in boot time.  What gives?

```
systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 2min 2.252s (firmware) + 7.057s (loader) + 1.749s (kernel) + 2min 58.356s (initrd) + 2min 50.312s (userspace) = 7min 59.728s 
graphical.target reached after 2min 50.281s in userspace.

systemd-analyze blame | head -n 20                                                                                                  
2min 58.726s dev-disk-by\x2ddiskseq-2.device
2min 58.726s dev-disk-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:1f.2\x2data\x2d1.device
2min 58.726s sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1f.2-ata1-host0-target0:0:0-0:0:0:0-block-sr0.device
2min 58.726s dev-sr0.device
2min 58.726s dev-disk-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:1f.2\x2data\x2d1.0.device
2min 58.726s dev-cdrom.device
2min 58.726s dev-disk-by\x2did-ata\x2dASUS_BW\x2d12B1ST_a_K9PF4GH0434.device
2min 58.716s sys-module-fuse.device
2min 58.692s dev-disk-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:1f.2\x2data\x2d2.0.device
2min 58.692s sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1f.2-ata2-host1-target1:0:0-1:0:0:0-block-sr1.device
2min 58.692s dev-sr1.device
2min 58.692s dev-disk-by\x2did-ata\x2dHL\x2dDT\x2dST_BD\x2dRE_WH16NS40_K93F23H1928.device
2min 58.692s dev-disk-by\x2ddiskseq-4.device
2min 58.692s dev-disk-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:00:1f.2\x2data\x2d2.device
2min 58.675s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS11.device
2min 58.675s dev-ttyS11.device
2min 58.675s dev-ttyS10.device
2min 58.675s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS10.device
2min 58.674s sys-devices-platform-serial8250-tty-ttyS1.device
2min 58.674s dev-ttyS1.device

systemd-analyze critical-chain                                                                                                       
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @2min 50.281s
└─multi-user.target @2min 50.281s
  └─plymouth-quit-wait.service @5.694s +2min 44.576s
    └─systemd-user-sessions.service @5.661s +21ms
      └─remote-fs.target @5.649s
        └─remote-fs-pre.target @5.649s
          └─nfs-client.target @2.618s
            └─gssproxy.service @2.591s +26ms
              └─network.target @2.581s
                └─wpa_supplicant.service @2min 49.191s +9ms
                  └─dbus-broker.service @2.148s +26ms
                    └─dbus.socket @2.043s
                      └─sysinit.target @2.040s
                        └─systemd-resolved.service @1.936s +104ms
                          └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @1.870s +48ms
                            └─import-state.service @1.794s +34ms
                              └─local-fs.target @1.793s
                                └─boot-efi.mount @1.778s +14ms
                                  └─boot.mount @1.446s +8ms
                                    └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-49e7acd7\x2d0f9e\x2d4eea\x2d905a\x2d224a26ff22e9.service @1.395s +28ms
                                      └─local-fs-pre.target @1.391s
                                        └─lvm2-monitor.service @723ms +666ms
                                          └─dm-event.socket @704ms
                                            └─system.slice
                                              └─-.slice
```

I'm out of ideas and I'm hoping someone can assist.  I'll be greatly appreciated it!

Comment: Could you maybe [Edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/734658/edit) the question and add the same outputs from the failure situation as well? Sorta useful for troubleshooting a failure :-) Also syslog output would be helpful in determining what's going on.

Comment: Updated it. I had to reboot to grab the failure so you beat me to it.  =)

Comment: Heh :-) Hope wiser heads can figure this out - my laptop's got the same card and I'm considering buying a second external monitor which would connect with DP...

Comment: If you're going to use DP, don't use NVidia.  I've been dealing with this issue for 2 weeks now.